# Understanding the scala substitution model through the use of sumInts method

Tags: scala, recursion

I'm doing a scala course and one of the examples given is the sumInts function which is defined like :

```
  def sumInts(a: Int, b: Int) : Int = 
    if(a > b) 0  
    else a + sumInts(a + 1 , b)
```

I've tried to understand this function better by outputting some values as its being iterated upon :

```
class SumInts {
      def sumInts(a: Int, b: Int) : Int = 
        if(a > b) 0 else 
        {     
          println(a + " + sumInts("+(a + 1)+" , "+b+")")       
          val res1 = sumInts(a + 1 , b)
          val res2 = a
          val res3 = res1 + res2
          println("res1 is : "+res1+", res2 is "+res2+", res3 is "+res3)
          res3
        }
}
```

So the code :

```
object SumIntsMain {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

      println(new SumInts().sumInts(3 , 6));

  }

}
```

Returns the output :

```
3 + sumInts(4 , 6)
4 + sumInts(5 , 6)
5 + sumInts(6 , 6)
6 + sumInts(7 , 6)
res1 is : 0, res2 is 6, res3 is 6
res1 is : 6, res2 is 5, res3 is 11
res1 is : 11, res2 is 4, res3 is 15
res1 is : 15, res2 is 3, res3 is 18
18
```

Can someone explain how these values are computed. I've tried by outputting all of the created variables but still im confused.

Comment: I think you posted the wrong code for main. Your main method does not even call your sumInts method.

Comment: @sepp2k apologies, I have updated the question

Comment: Let's try something simpler: `def sumTo(n: Int): Int = if (n <= 0) 0 else n + sumTo(n-1)`.  Can you understand that one?

Comment: @Rex Kerr thanks, but im not looking for a simpler algorithm just to work though the one posted.

Comment: @user701254 - If you can't understand the harder one with those printouts, then you ought to try a simpler analog to develop your ability to think about recursion.

Comment: What is the "Scala substitution model"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

manual-human-tracer on:

```
return sumInts(3, 6) | a = 3, b = 6
3 > 6 ? NO
return 3 + sumInts(3 + 1, 6) | a = 4, b = 6
4 > 6 ? NO
return 3 + (4 + sumInts(4 + 1, 6)) | a = 5, b = 6
5 > 6 ? NO
return 3 + (4 + (5 + sumInts(5 + 1, 6))) | a = 6, b = 6
6 > 6 ? NO
return 3 + (4 + (5 + (6 + sumInts(6 + 1, 6)))) | a = 7, b = 6
7 > 6 ? YEEEEES (return 0)
return 3 + (4 + (5 + (6 + 0))) = return 18.
```

manual-human-tracer off.

Answer (score 5):

To understand what recursive code does, it's not necessary to analyze the recursion tree. In fact, I believe it's often just confusing.

### Pretending it works

Let's think about what we're trying to do: We want to sum all integers starting at `a` until some integer `b`.

> a + sumInts(a + 1 , b)

Let us just pretend that `sumInts(a + 1, b)` actually does what we want it to: Summing the integers from `a + 1` to `b`. If we accept this as truth, it's quite clear that our function will handle the larger problem, from `a` to `b` correctly. Because clearly, all that is missing from the sum is the additional term `a`, which is simply added. We conclude that it must work correctly.

### A foundation: The base case

However, this `sumInts()` must be built on something: The base case, where no recursion is involved.

> if(a > b) 0

Looking closely at our recursive call, we can see that it makes certain assumptions: we expect `a` to be lower than `b`. This implies that the sum will look like this:  `a + (a + 1) + ... + (b - 1) + b`. If `a` is bigger than `b`, this sum naturally evaluates to 0.

### Making sure it works

Seeing that `sumInts()` always increases `a` by one in the recursive call guarantees, that we will in fact hit the base case at some point.

Noticing further, that `sumInts(b, b)` will be called eventually, we can now verify that the code works: Since `b` is not greater than itself, the second case will be invoked: `b + sumInts(b + 1, b)`. From here, it is obvious that this will evaluate to: `b + 0`, which means our algorithm works correctly for all values.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the substitution model, so let's apply it to your `sumInts` method:

We start by calling `sumInts(3,4)` (you've used 6 as the second argument, but I chose 4, so I can type less), so let's substitute 3 for `a` and 4 for `b` in the definition of `sumInts`. This gives us:

```
if(3 > 4) 0  
else 3 + sumInts(3 + 1, 4)
```

So, what will the result of this be? Well, `3 > 4` is clearly false, so the end result will be equal to the else clause, i.e. 3 plus the result of `sumInts(4, 4)` (4 being the result of `3+1`). Now we need to know what the result of `sumInts(4, 4)` will be. For that we can substitute again (this time substituting 4 for `a` and `b`):

```
if(4 > 4) 0
else 4 + sumInts(4 + 1, 4)
```

Okay, so the result of `sumInts(4,4)` will be 4 plus the result of `sumInts(5,4)`. So what's `sumInts(5,4)`? To the substitutionator!

```
if(5 > 4) 0
else 5 + sumInts(5 + 1, 4)
```

This time the if condition is true, so the result of `sumInts(5,4)` is 0. So now we know that the result of `sumInts(4,4)` must be `4 + 0` which is 4. And thus the result of `sumInts(3,4)` must be `3 + 4`, which is 7.